# SSL warning appears only to some devices

Tags: ssl, https, certificate-authority

I have godaddy ssl certificate for domain.There wasn't any problems with my SSL certificate and visiting my domain(Haven't receiveed any errors), but couple times(two weeks ago) when I visited site from other(mobile, tablet and desktop) devices(different internet) I received SSL warning. I tested my domain on sslshopper.com and in this system shows that everything is okay with our SSL(Expiry date in 200 days). But I tested my SSL in ssllabs.com and SSL got only C grade. Maybe you have any idea why such stuff happening? Is it possible that if we would change SSL to other one, there wouldn't be such error at all? Maybe you experienced something similar and you can help out. Because warning appears only sometimes and in different devices, but other than that everything is perfect

Comment: ssllabs.com will tell you what problems there are with your certificate. Did you read the report?

Comment: Missing intermediate certificate, maybe?

Comment: Agreed - verify that your entire cert chain is intact.